# Alternatives to printf() for MISRA C : 2004 compliant code

Tags: c, stdio, misra

I am new to coding using MISRA C guidelines.

The following are two rules in MISRA C 2004:

**Rule 16.1 (required): Functions shall not be defined with a variable number of arguments.
Rule 20.9 (required): The input/output library `<stdio.h>` shall not be used in production code.**

This clearly means that I can't use `printf` in production code for it to be MISRA C compliant, because `printf` is a part of `<stdio.h>` and allows a variable number of arguments. So I set out on a quest to find out how I can write my own `printf` statement. So far I am unable to find any solution for this predicament. Any help from fellow developers would be appreciated.

Comment: If you wrote your own "*printf*" it would end up being a variadic function as well. So first step would be to decide *what* part(s) of printf you need which don't require a variable number of arguments.

Comment: There may be some inspiration here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528389/printing-a-number-without-using-printf

Comment: Huh why did you add "closed" to the topic? That's not how closing works. If you are getting frustrated about various PC programmer answers, you could add the [tag:embedded] tag to the question to scare them away. Overall it would be helpful to know exactly what kind of systems and hardware you are targeting.

Comment: Also, any reason why you are using the old MISRA-C:2004 and not the latest one? (They have the same requirements in this specific case though.)

Comment: @Lundin I have unclosed it :-)  I like this question, and it will be helpful to others.

Comment: @Lundin I added {closed} to the topic as I decided to go for deviation of the above rules

Comment: Okay so a generic lib. But what do you need printf for in that case? Just for testing? MISRA allows you to use stdio.h in debug release, just not in production. Or in case you need some manner of logging, you could just create a function dropping a string to the caller and then let the caller worry about how to present it.

Comment: @Lundin huh, didn't think of that, thanks for the suggestion, also yeah, I do need printf for logging

Answer (score 4):

> so far I am unable to find any solution for this predicament

You have to use functions that print one (countable) things at a time. An example interface you might want to implement might look like the following:

```
print_string("Hello");
print_int(5);
print_char('\n');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately the functions that you mention run on x86 based processors only, I am working on creating a library acting as a middleware between different types of processor, based on both x86 and arm architecture. So, even though this is a solution for those using processors based of x86, this doesn't support every architecture, anyways, thanks for the reply! I think I will go for documented deviation

Comment: You might want to state that in the question. GIGO, and all that ;-)

Comment: `the functions that you mention run on x86 based processors` `this doesn't support every architecture` I do not understand. Surely every architecture that has C compiler supports functions with one argument. What functions are mentioned? These `print_int` and other I listed here are abstract functions that show sample possible interface, that you might want to implement. Still, the implementation can be portable, with only the `putchar` part being implementation specific.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, I am confused by that response as well. I've implemented this exact thing for 8 and 32 bit microcontrollers before (actually before I understood how variadic magic actually worked). It's clunky, but if you must avoid VAR ARGS it works.

Answer (score 1):

> so I set out on a quest to find out how I can write my own printf statement

Most MISRA-C systems are embedded systems where `printf` is just some bloated wrapper around an UART library. The usual solution is to develop your own logging/messaging tool instead. Not necessarily UART-based, might as well some other serial bus, or just 8 parallel data or some LCD/7-seg... all depending on what you need to display and if you intend for this to be part of the production code or not.

So how to do this is highly project-specific and it's typically more of a system design and electronics problem than a programming one.

EDIT

Since you seem to be making some sort of general-purpose library, one solution is to simply provide an API that returns strings to the caller, then let the caller worry about how to present them. That makes your lib MISRA-C compliant, while allowing the caller to print strings in whatever application-specific way they have available. For example:

```
void lib_getmsg (char* msg, size_t bufsize);
```

Where "lib" is some prefix for your library. Leave string allocation to the caller. Alternatively, the old-fashioned way:

```
lib_result_t  lib_dosomething (void);

// Returns LIB_OK if went OK, returns LIB_ERR in case of errors.
// To get more information, call lib_get_lastmsg.

const char* lib_get_lastmsg (void);
```

This returns a pointer to an internal `static` string allocated by your library. The downside of this is that it won't work well in multi-process environments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the rationale for the MISRA C guidelines, understand the context they are used in, and the circumstances of your own code.

You also need to understand that the MISRA Guidelines are not to be blindly followed with a tick-box mentality... you then need to appreciate that those nice folk at MISRA provide several chapters of useful material before the actual guidelines.  Part of that is the Deviation procedure.

If you can justify why you feel you need to violate a guidelines, then use the deviation procedure that is specified.  This requires you understand the nature of the violation, and what you are going to do to ensure the integrity of your application.

If you genuinely need to use `printf()` and you can justify that, use it with a deviation

Answer (score -1):

On Linux, running on a modern x86_64 processor:

```
int main()
{
    char *s = "Hello, World!\n";
    long l = 14;
    long fd = 1;
    long syscall = 1;
    long ret = 0;
    __asm__("syscall"
            : "=a"(ret)
            : "a"(syscall),
              "D"(fd),
              "S"(s),
              "d"(l));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Thanks Criss! unfortunately I am using MISRA C guidelines to write a code for a library that can run on processors of different architecture, so even though this is another solution, it won't work for me, anyways I have decided to go for deviation of those 2 rules I mentioned earlier. Thanks for your valuable guidance!

Comment: So, if it won't work for you, why did you accept it as the answer?

Comment: This is very far from MISRA-C compliant either, so it isn't not helpful. You'd have to use stdint.h types, you have to encapsulate inline asm and so on. But it's quite rare to have MISRA-C requirements on a x86 Linux program, I think.