# Why my printf in C removes an element of array?

Tags: arrays, c

**Hello  guys, i have this code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    int numberPosition=8;
    char senha[1000]="01000hello";
    printf("%i\n", numberPosition);
    senha[numberPosition]="";
    printf("\n%s\n", senha);
    
    return 0;
    }
```

When I executes my code my return is: *01000heo*.

However if I delete the line `"printf("%d\n", numberPosition);"` my return is: *01000helo*

**Why printf deletes an element from my array?**

Comment: `senha[numberPosition]="";` What do you intend that to do? Why are you assigning a string to a `char` variable?

Comment: 1. It doesn't. 2. `senha[numberPosition]="";` is a bad idea & messes things up. Adjust your warning settings on your compiler so that you get one there & then fix. Don't know what you intend by that line, but it makes no sense.

Comment: It's an exercise in encryption. So the encryption gives an RNG in binary where it adds a random character in the String[BinariePosition] so to decrypt I need to delete this char String[BinariePosition] from my string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove the character at a given index from a string in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457608/how-to-remove-the-character-at-a-given-index-from-a-string-in-c)

Comment: The _accident_ happened before `printf()` was called. Don't blame proven to be reliable library functions when your code doesn't do what you want it to do. Sorry... The title and question should be, "What have **I** done wrong in this code?"

Comment: What you tried doesn't remove a character, it replaces one with a semi-random value. That value may not necessarily be a printable character.

Comment: Did you get any compiler warnings? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings

Comment: Basic novice tips for this code: 1. Enable compiler warnings, `-Wall -Wextra` for _gcc_ and _clang_, `/W4` for _MSVC_. Then fix warnings in your own code! 2. Use `{}`, even when you don't have to, and use auto-indent or auto-format/beautify on your code.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Well, while I overall agree with that, that "proven to be reliable" may be [a bit too optimistic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741172/alternatives-to-printf-for-misra-c-2004-compliant-code).

Comment: @Bob__ So, as the Golgifrinchans(?) (Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy) said about why they hadn't yet invented the wheel, "Well you tell us what colour it should be!!!" I don't know the standard described at that link, but... I'll stick with <stdio.h> & Co. over and above what most _boutique_ alternatives might offer. "No one ever got fired for buying IBM!!" `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`senha[numberPosition]="";` is problematic as the left side is expecting a `char` but the right side is a `char *` which is then implicitly cast to an integer.  This is often an error and gcc will generate a warning.  Here is the explicit cast:

```
senha[numberPosition]=(unsigned long) "";
```

This will convert the address where the string "" is stored to an integer.  It happens to evaluate to `8` which is backspace `\b`:

```
./a.out | od -a
0000000   8  nl  nl   0   1   0   0   0   h   e   l  bs   o  nl
0000016
```

[what you want, what you really, really want](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gJLIiF15wjQ) is:

```
senha[numberPosition]='\0';
```

which will print:

```
8

01000hel
```

You clarified you wanted the output "01000helo" and either of these produce that output for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int numberPosition=8;
    char senha[1000]="01000hello";
    senha[numberPosition] = 'o';
    senha[numberPosition+1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", senha);
}
```

or:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int numberPosition=8;
    char senha[1000]="01000hello";
    strcpy(senha + numberPosition, "o");
    printf("%s\n", senha);
}
```

It would be a good idea to add boundary checks.

Your comment below talks about removing characters which is a different problem that you initially described.   You want to check out `memmove()` (which permit overlap of `dst`, `src`, unlike `strcpy()`, `memcpy()`).

Comment: Didn't actually click the link, but saw "...youtube..."... Are you (quite understandably!) _losing it_ (after all these sorts of questions?) `:-)` **Strongly** advise a bit of an intermission if this is getting to you... `:-)`

Comment: thanks for the explanation about string/char*, however I need the output `01000helo` as the output. I will try the 'remove char from string' as mentioned a little while ago

Comment: Then you do `senha[numberPosition]='o'; senha[numberPosition+1]='\0'` or `strcpy(senha + numberPosition, "o")`.

Comment: doesn't worked for me. that method return `01000heloo` instead `01000helo`  Im using `void removeChar(char *str, unsigned int index) {   char *src;  for (src = str+index; *src != '\0'; *src = *(src+1),++src) ;  *src = '\0';}`  and  its working 100% for me